# How do I determine the maximum gas required for a truffle deploy?

Tags: truffle

I have a smart contract with some initialization logic and I'm trying to test it locally with `truffle develop`.

When I migrate, I run into:

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas
```

Should I be setting a higher 'max' via [this](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/migrations#deployer-deploy-contract-args-options-)?

And if so, how do I determine what that should be (just for local development/testing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the configuration file of truffle at gas value:

```
module.exports = {
// See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
// to customize your Truffle configuration!
networks: {
  rinkeby: {
    host: "localhost", // Connect to geth on the specified
    port: 8545,
    from: "0x58E891Bf0a0C3F89Fb6E120305841471fb363391", // default address to 
    use for any transaction Truffle makes during migrations
    network_id: 4,
    gas: 6712390 // Gas limit used for deploys
  }
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The gas limit is called the limit because it's the maximum amount of units of gas you are willing to spend on a transaction.
The units of gas necessary for a transaction are already defined by how much code is executed on the blockchain.You must include enough gas to cover the computational resources you use or your transaction will fail due to an `Out of Gas` Error.
All unused gas is refunded to you at the end of a transaction.

you can get the gas limit of block by eth.getBlock('latest') and checking gasLimit parameter in it.